# Will the same lambda be created multiple times in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
void do_something(std::function<void(void)> callback){
    callback();
}

int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < 10000000) {
        do_something([&](){  std::cout << "by reference:" << counter << endl;  });
        do_something([=](){  std::cout << "by value:" << counter << endl;  });
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

As shown in the above code, will a new lambda be created in each loop? Will there be a difference with capturing a value or a reference?

I've been searching for some articles, but I'm still not quite sure. I believe value-capturing lambdas need to be created multiple times, while reference-capturing ones probably don't.

If a lambda captured by reference can be reused, will the copying of the lambda still happen? For example, will the following two functions still make a difference?

```
void do_something2(std::function<void(void)> callback){
    callback();
}

void do_something2(std::function<void(void)> & callback){
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean, the definition of the lambda is only created once. The instance of the object of the lambda is created many times. [Try c++ insights](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPGZpbGVzeXN0ZW0+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxjaHJvbm8+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDxpb3N0cmVhbT4KI2luY2x1ZGUgPGZ1bmN0aW9uYWw+Cgp1c2luZyBuYW1lc3BhY2Ugc3RkOwoKICB2b2lkIGRvX3NvbWV0aGluZyhzdGQ6OmZ1bmN0aW9uPHZvaWQodm9pZCk+IGNhbGxiYWNrKXsKICAgICAgCiAgICBjYWxsYmFjaygpOwogIH0KCiAgaW50IG1haW4oKSB7CiAgICBpbnQgY291bnRlciA9IDA7CiAgICB3aGlsZShjb3VudGVyIDwgNSkgewogICAgICBkb19zb21ldGhpbmcoWyZdKCl7ICBzdGQ6OmNvdXQgPDwgImJ5IHJlZmVyZW5jZToiIDw8IGNvdW50ZXIgPDwgZW5kbDsgIH0pOwogICAgICBkb19zb21ldGhpbmcoWz1dKCl7ICBzdGQ6OmNvdXQgPDwgImJ5IHZhbHVlOiIgPDwgY291bnRlciA8PCBlbmRsOyAgfSk7CiAgICAgICsrY291bnRlcjsKICAgIH0KICB9&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) it can give you a lot of interesting information. For example in your case:

```
 while(counter < 5) {
            
      class __lambda_16_20
      {
        public: 
        inline /*constexpr */ void operator()() const
        {
          std::operator<<(std::cout, "by reference:").operator<<(counter).operator<<(std::endl);
        }
        
        private: 
        int & counter;
        public: 
        // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_16_20(const __lambda_16_20 &) noexcept = default;
        // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_16_20(__lambda_16_20 &&) noexcept = default;
        __lambda_16_20(int & _counter)
        : counter{_counter}
        {}
        
      };
      
      do_something(std::function<void ()>(__lambda_16_20{counter}));
```

You can see the definition of the lambda is generated inside the while, but only 1 time. The instance of the object (in this case `__lambda_16_20` is created each time you go through the loop.

In your example with:

```
void do_something2(std::function<void(void)> & callback)
```

yes, this will change things. Because you are asking for a non-const reference, this value can no longer be temporary. Which means this:

```
do_something2([=](){  std::cout << "by value:" << counter << endl;  });
```

Will not compile. Instead you will need a modifiable value:

```
auto my_lambda = [=](){  std::cout << "by value:" << counter << endl;  };
do_something(my_lambda{});
```

Whether you make `my_lambda` in the loop or outside the loop is up to you. Then you will need to double check how you use capture by reference vs capture by value.

Comment: If instances were created in every loop, for the lambda capturing by reference, does pulling the lambda definition outside the loop avoid the cost of construction?

Comment: By the way , if we make sure callback is lambda capturing by reference, always use 
"void do_something(std::function<void(void)> & callback)" will be better than "void do_something(std::function<void(void)> callback)"?

Comment: For Q1 it does, but what is the "cost of constructing the lambda" Make sure you avoid pre-mature optimisation because you may make your code harder to follow and the results of profiling may surprise you. Continually passing a reference may be slower than passing by value, because your compiler may be able to just optimise everything to do with this away.

Comment: For Q2, what does "better" mean? More readable? Certainly not. Faster? Maybe, but maybe not, you would need to profile the real example.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Your proposed change to the non-const reference case does not solve it, because a reference to a `std::function<...>` is needed. In the suggested code, there is still a conversion from the lambda to `std::function<...>` that creates a temporary object that cannot bind to the non-const reference.

Comment: @j6t true, but i didn't propose this is a solution. The OP asked about this case. My suggested solution would be to use the lambda as is, the compiler will optimise this away and this is unlikely to be the source of any real bottleneck.